# Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have some troubles when I try to start my go application with docker.
`ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./main\": permission denied": unknown`
It happenes when I try to do `docker-compose up`

It is my mulristage Dockerfil:

```
# Dockerfile References: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

# Start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:1.13 as builder

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /memesbot

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o /memesbot/cmd/main .

######## Start a new stage from scratch #######
FROM alpine:latest


RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /memesbot/cmd/main .

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

And docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    environment:
      TELEGRAM_TOKEN: xxxyyy
```

Does somebody know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the permission to your executable it should work.

```
RUN chmod +x ./main
# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

Comment: Just do it locally on your filesystem.

Comment: Adding the `RUN` to the file didn't work.  I had to apply `chmod` directly to the local file.  Let me know if there's an alternative since this meant we had to update the readme for developers since this was an issue where Mac only didn't have permissions, and there was no issues on Windows

Comment: The above will work in case of multi-stage build, if you consuming from host then set permission on host as mentioned but that might be the case if you are using mounting?

Comment: Applying the permission locally did worked for me on macos.